# Connecting to Siebel using Java databeans hangs forever

Tags: java, siebel

Hi Below is a sample code I've written:

```
import com.siebel.data.*;
import com.siebel.data.SiebelException;

public class DataBeanDemo
{
   private SiebelDataBean m_dataBean = null;
   private SiebelBusObject   m_busObject = null;
   private SiebelBusComp       m_busComp = null;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      DataBeanDemo demo = new DataBeanDemo();
   }

   public DataBeanDemo()
   {
      try
      {
         m_dataBean = new SiebelDataBean();

         m_dataBean.login("Siebel://devServerXYZ:7777/XYZ/
          ecommunication_enu", ROSADMIN, ROSADMIN, "enu");

         System.out.println("Connected");

         m_busObject = m_dataBean.getBusObject("Opportunity");

         m_busComp = m_busObject.getBusComp("Opportunity");

         m_dataBean.logoff();
      }

      catch (SiebelException e)
      {
         System.out.println(e.getErrorMessage());
      }
   }
}
```

This code executes without issues, but gets stuck at `m_dataBean.login()`. And never returns.

What could be the issue?

If I try to change connect string (even port name, from 7777 to any other number like 2320, 2321) then I get error `could not open a session in 4 attempts SBL-JCA-00200`.

Comment: As the Java bean connects with the object manager (typically on port 2321) any internal problems should feature in the object manager log file. Do you have the corresponding log file for your connection attempt?

Comment: It doesn't have any logs generated

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried or suspect?

Comment: Posting my answer, I was able to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 things to verify

1. Parameters in the connect string. Gtway server name, OM comp name, port number etc. (Username/Password error is showed immediately but rest others throw generic errors or hung forever)
2. (This is something that's specific to Siebel) Ensure that Java subsystem profile has classpath pointing to siebel.jar and siebelJI_lang.jar files
3. Siebel Server is up and running.

If LDAP is true, then such logins cannot be used using Databeans.

In my case it was 1 & 2, that was causing issues. By the way Comp name is case sensitive.

Comment: Is this issue now resolved? If so, can you be a little more specific what exactly caused your issue and what the resolution was? If possible, can you provide a working example code?

Comment: Code remains same, except that I corrected case-sensitivity. And for 2nd point, we need to check server configuration. 
Either through shellscript or viewing/editing config/properties file.